# What to eat to maintain regular thyroid activity?

Tags: diet, thyroid, hyperthyroid, hypothyroid, iodine

My friend has hypothyroidism and I have had hyperthyroidism in the past. What foods can people eat or avoid to assist in regulating our thyroids? I remember something about Iodine, perhaps? Please clarify whether a food helps hypo (and perhaps should be avoided by hyper) and vice versa.

Comment: What makes you think food can be enough to regulate thyroid function?

Comment: This question needs to be more specific before it can be reasonably answered. It should either ask about hypo, or hyper, but not both, or alternatively ask about which foods are appropriate no matter which condition one has.

Comment: @Highly Irregular Why wouldn't you ask for both? Wouldn't it be logical to assume that hyper & hypo are dependently correlated relative to consumption of a food? For example, if you know that a food lowers your blood pressure, then you would want to consume it when you have high blood pressure.

Comment: @HighlyIrregular "which foods are appropriate no matter which condition one has..." I'm not a doctor, but I'm pretty sure that category includes basically anything that humans consider food. Look, I understand that asking for hypo/hyper may encompass a reasonably sizable zone, but given that I'm asking specifically benefits from diet, I don't imagine volumes written on this answer, and based on the assumption(may or may not be accurate) that hypo/hyper operate dependently relative to same food, then I believe this question is fair. To discuss further, let's chat privately.

Comment: @HighlyIrregular didn't you just ask a question about both? ;-) I think the scope is okay.

Comment: @YviDe If you don't think there's still an issue with the post, could you please consider retracting close votes? 3-votes is making me feel edgy about getting closed by hive-minded voters. I'd be happy to fix anything that doesn't seem clear or misguiding, and thanks for contributing!

Comment: @DaveL My original problem wasn't with the scope, but seeing that edit, I have retracted my vote. Hyperthyroidism and hyperthyroidism both can have various causes, though, and hypothyroidism is not just a reverse of hyperthyroidism, so I don't think your assumption that food that helps in one situation should be avoided in the other follows, but a possible answer can tackle that

Comment: @YviDe I was hoping that someone does address that, since there are plenty of questions that may have some wrong assumptions, but can be even more useful due to addressing both the question and correcting the assumption. In this case though, it seems to be causing more ruckus than it's worth. I've edited as a result. I still hope someone clarifies on their relationship.

Comment: @YviDe fair point... I definite look like a hypocrite, though I think my question has a reasonably narrow focus. For what it's worth, I think this is a great question, but a very broad one, and I hope we get some good answers. I'm happy to leave it open and see what happens.